# Fill in Missing Dates and Time in Quarterly Time Series According to Subgroup

Tags: r, date, data.table

I have data of following type, just much bigger than this.

```
DIST TALUK HOBLI CODE DATE      REC_TIME    RAIN
DK  P1  A1  1503    01-06-19    00:00:00    22.5
DK  P1  A1  1503    01-06-19    00:15:00    23.0
DK  P1  A1  1503    01-06-19    00:30:00    23.0
DK  P1  A1  1503    01-06-19    00:45:00    23.0
DK  P1  A1  1503    01-06-19    01:00:00    23.0
DK  P1  A1  1503    01-06-19    01:15:00    23.0
DK  P1  A1  1503    01-06-19    01:30:00    23.0
DK  P1  A1  1503    01-06-19    01:45:00    23.0
DK  P1  A1  1503    01-06-19    02:00:00    23.0
DK  P1  A2  515     01-06-19    22:15:00    23.0
DK  P1  A2  515     01-06-19    22:30:00    23.0
DK  P1  A2  515     01-06-19    22:45:00    23.0
DK  P1  A2  515     01-06-19    23:00:00    23.0
DK  P2  A3  633     01-07-19    22:15:00    23.0
DK  P2  A3  633     01-07-19    22:30:00    24.0
DK  P2  A3  633     01-07-19    22:45:00    24.0
DK  P2  A3  633     01-07-19    23:00:00    24.0
DK  P2  A3  633     01-07-19    23:15:00    24.0
DK  P2  A3  633     01-07-19    23:30:00    29.0
DK  P2  A3  633     01-07-19    23:45:00    32.0
DK  P2  A3  633     02-07-19    00:00:00    36.0
DK  P2  A3  633     02-07-19    00:15:00    36.0
DK  P3  B1  845     01-06-19    05:30:00    36.0
DK  P3  B1  845     01-06-19    05:45:00    36.0
DK  P3  B1  845     01-06-19    06:00:00    36.0
DK  P3  B1  845     01-06-19    06:15:00    36.0
DK  P3  B1  845     01-06-19    06:30:00    36.0
DK  P3  B1  845     01-06-19    06:45:00    36.0
DK  P3  B1  845     01-06-19    07:00:00    36.0
DK  P3  B1  845     01-06-19    07:15:00    36.0
DK  P3  B2  789     01-06-19    07:30:00    36.0
DK  P3  B2  789     01-06-19    07:45:00    36.0
DK  P3  B2  789     01-06-19    08:00:00    36.0
DK  P3  B2  789     01-06-19    08:15:00    36.0
DK  P3  B2  789     01-06-19    08:30:00    36.0
DK  P3  B2  789     01-06-19    08:45:00    0.0
DK  P3  B2  789     01-06-19    09:00:00    0.0
DK  P3  B2  789     01-06-19    09:15:00    0.0
DK  P3  B2  789     01-06-19    09:30:00    0.0
DK  P4  B4  801     22-08-19    00:00:00    0.0
DK  P4  B4  801     22-08-19    00:15:00    0.0
DK  P4  B4  801     22-08-19    00:30:00    0.5
DK  P4  B4  801     22-08-19    00:45:00    0.5
DK  P4  B4  801     22-08-19    22:30:00    0.5
DK  P4  B4  801     22-08-19    22:45:00    0.5
DK  P4  B4  801     30-11-19    21:45:00    0.5
DK  P4  B4  801     30-11-19    22:00:00    0.5
DK  P4  B4  801     30-11-19    22:15:00    0.5
DK  P4  B4  801     30-11-19    22:30:00    2.0
DK  P4  B4  801     30-11-19    22:45:00    5.5
DK  P4  B4  801     30-11-19    23:00:00    5.5
DK  P4  B4  801     30-11-19    23:15:00    5.5
DK  P4  B4  801     30-11-19    23:30:00    5.5
DK  P4  B4  801     30-11-19    23:45:00    5.5
```

Data starts from `01-06-19` (01-Jun-19) to `30-11-19` (30-Nov-19) and every hour has four readings but for some stations observations of some days and time in this sequence are missing. I want to fill in those missing DATES and REC_TIME such that every station has observations from 01-06-19 to 30-11-19. The variable RAIN for such DATES and REC_TIME should be filled with NA.

I tried several options suggested by peoples in stack overflow, but didn't get desired result.
I also tried following :

```
df_1 <- df[, .(RECORDED_DATE = seq(as.Date(min(df$RECORDED_DATE)), as.Date(max(df$RECORDED_DATE)), "day")), by = list(DISTRICT, TALUKNAME, HOBLINAME, TRGCODE, HOUR)]
```

It took too much time in processing and resulting output was like:

```
DIST TALUK HOBLI CODE DATE      REC_TIME    RAIN
DK  P1  A1  1503    01-06-19    00:00:00    22.5
DK  P1  A1  1503    02-06-19    00:00:00    00.0
DK  P1  A1  1503    03-06-19    00:00:00    01.0
DK  P1  A1  1503    04-06-19    00:00:00    03.0
DK  P1  A1  1503    05-06-19    00:00:00    00.0
DK  P1  A1  1503    06-06-19    00:00:00    15.0
DK  P1  A1  1503    07-06-19    00:00:00    09.0
DK  P1  A1  1503    08-06-19    00:00:00    05.0
DK  P1  A1  1503    09-06-19    00:00:00    13.0
```

I also tried `tidyverse`, complete but didn't get desired result as there was error in data frame. Data has DATE as CHARACTER and after using `tidyverse` or complete its converting it into DOUBLE, so merging is not happening. I tried to convert CHARACTER to NUMERIC but result was DATE column filled with NA's. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, we can combine date and time column with `unite`, then create a sequence of every 15 mins from `min` and `max` `DATETIME` and get date and time in separate columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  unite(DATETIME, DATE, REC_TIME, sep = " ", remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(DATETIME = as.POSIXct(DATETIME, format = "%d-%m-%y %T", tz = "UTC")) %>%
  complete(CODE, DATETIME = seq(min(DATETIME), max(DATETIME), by = "15 min")) %>%
  mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATETIME), REC_TIME = format(DATETIME, "%T")) %>%
  select(-DATETIME) %>%
  group_by(CODE) %>%
  fill(DIST, TALUK, HOBLI, .direction = "updown")
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(DIST = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "DK", class = "factor"), 
TALUK = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("P1", 
"P2", "P3", "P4"), class = "factor"), HOBLI = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("A1", "A2", "A3", 
"B1", "B2", "B4"), class = "factor"), CODE = c(1503L, 1503L, 
1503L, 1503L, 1503L, 1503L, 1503L, 1503L, 1503L, 515L, 515L, 
515L, 515L, 633L, 633L, 633L, 633L, 633L, 633L, 633L, 633L, 
633L, 845L, 845L, 845L, 845L, 845L, 845L, 845L, 845L, 789L, 
789L, 789L, 789L, 789L, 789L, 789L, 789L, 789L, 801L, 801L, 
801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 
801L, 801L, 801L), DATE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("01-06-19", "01-07-19", "02-07-19", 
"22-08-19", "30-11-19"), class = "factor"), REC_TIME = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 30L, 31L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L), .Label = c("00:00:00", "00:15:00", "00:30:00", 
"00:45:00", "01:00:00", "01:15:00", "01:30:00", "01:45:00", 
"02:00:00", "05:30:00", "05:45:00", "06:00:00", "06:15:00", 
"06:30:00", "06:45:00", "07:00:00", "07:15:00", "07:30:00", 
"07:45:00", "08:00:00", "08:15:00", "08:30:00", "08:45:00", 
"09:00:00", "09:15:00", "09:30:00", "21:45:00", "22:00:00", 
"22:15:00", "22:30:00", "22:45:00", "23:00:00", "23:15:00", 
"23:30:00", "23:45:00"), class = "factor"), RAIN = c(22.5, 
23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 
24, 24, 29, 32, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 
36, 36, 36, 36, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 2, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -54L))
```

Comment: It gave the error as: Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number and further can we assign corresponding names and station codes instead of NA for missing DATE.

Comment: @Ajay Which is your station code column? If it is `DIST` change the `complete` line to `complete(DIST, DATETIME = seq(min(DATETIME), max(DATETIME), by = "15 min"))`. To full corresponding svalues you can add  `%>% fill(everything())` at the end to fill the values.

Comment: Station code column is represented by CODE column in above data set. I'm still getting error as Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number. Do I need to write seq(as.Date(min(DATETIME))) but DATETIME is not Date object so I can't write like that.

Comment: @Ajay I have updated the data that I am using. Can you check if you get the answer using that data?

Comment: According to your data set it assigns NA everywhere to RAIN column

Comment: Is the error because of data type? Your data set has DATE and REC_TIME in factor type and mine data set has it in character type.

Comment: Sorry I didn't check it properly, It has values in RAIN column

Answer (score 1):

If your dataset is big, this might be faster option using `data.table`:

```
ans <- DT[CJ(CODE, dt=seq(min(dt), max(dt), by="15 mins"), unique=TRUE), 
    on=.(CODE, dt), roll="nearest"]

ans[DateTime!=dt, `:=` (
    .(DATE=format(dt, format="%d-%m-%y"), 
        REC_TIME=format(dt, format="%H:%M:%S"), 
        RAIN=NA_real_)
    )][,
        DateTime := NULL]
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("DIST TALUK HOBLI CODE DATE      REC_TIME    RAIN
DK  P1  A1  1503    01-06-19    00:00:00    22.5
DK  P1  A1  1503    01-06-19    00:15:00    23.0
DK  P1  A1  1503    01-06-19    00:30:00    23.0
DK  P1  A1  1503    01-06-19    00:45:00    23.0
DK  P1  A1  1503    01-06-19    01:00:00    23.0
DK  P1  A1  1503    01-06-19    01:15:00    23.0
DK  P1  A1  1503    01-06-19    01:30:00    23.0
DK  P1  A1  1503    01-06-19    01:45:00    23.0
DK  P1  A1  1503    01-06-19    02:00:00    23.0
DK  P1  A2  515     01-06-19    22:15:00    23.0
DK  P1  A2  515     01-06-19    22:30:00    23.0
DK  P1  A2  515     01-06-19    22:45:00    23.0
DK  P1  A2  515     01-06-19    23:00:00    23.0
DK  P2  A3  633     01-07-19    22:15:00    23.0
DK  P2  A3  633     01-07-19    22:30:00    24.0
DK  P2  A3  633     01-07-19    22:45:00    24.0
DK  P2  A3  633     01-07-19    23:00:00    24.0
DK  P2  A3  633     01-07-19    23:15:00    24.0
DK  P2  A3  633     01-07-19    23:30:00    29.0
DK  P2  A3  633     01-07-19    23:45:00    32.0
DK  P2  A3  633     02-07-19    00:00:00    36.0
DK  P2  A3  633     02-07-19    00:15:00    36.0
DK  P3  B1  845     01-06-19    05:30:00    36.0
DK  P3  B1  845     01-06-19    05:45:00    36.0
DK  P3  B1  845     01-06-19    06:00:00    36.0
DK  P3  B1  845     01-06-19    06:15:00    36.0
DK  P3  B1  845     01-06-19    06:30:00    36.0
DK  P3  B1  845     01-06-19    06:45:00    36.0
DK  P3  B1  845     01-06-19    07:00:00    36.0
DK  P3  B1  845     01-06-19    07:15:00    36.0
DK  P3  B2  789     01-06-19    07:30:00    36.0
DK  P3  B2  789     01-06-19    07:45:00    36.0
DK  P3  B2  789     01-06-19    08:00:00    36.0
DK  P3  B2  789     01-06-19    08:15:00    36.0
DK  P3  B2  789     01-06-19    08:30:00    36.0
DK  P3  B2  789     01-06-19    08:45:00    0.0
DK  P3  B2  789     01-06-19    09:00:00    0.0
DK  P3  B2  789     01-06-19    09:15:00    0.0
DK  P3  B2  789     01-06-19    09:30:00    0.0
DK  P4  B4  801     22-08-19    00:00:00    0.0
DK  P4  B4  801     22-08-19    00:15:00    0.0
DK  P4  B4  801     22-08-19    00:30:00    0.5
DK  P4  B4  801     22-08-19    00:45:00    0.5
DK  P4  B4  801     22-08-19    22:30:00    0.5
DK  P4  B4  801     22-08-19    22:45:00    0.5
DK  P4  B4  801     30-11-19    21:45:00    0.5
DK  P4  B4  801     30-11-19    22:00:00    0.5
DK  P4  B4  801     30-11-19    22:15:00    0.5
DK  P4  B4  801     30-11-19    22:30:00    2.0
DK  P4  B4  801     30-11-19    22:45:00    5.5
DK  P4  B4  801     30-11-19    23:00:00    5.5
DK  P4  B4  801     30-11-19    23:15:00    5.5
DK  P4  B4  801     30-11-19    23:30:00    5.5
DK  P4  B4  801     30-11-19    23:45:00    5.5")
DT[, dt := as.POSIXct(paste0(DATE, REC_TIME), format="%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S")][,
    DateTime := dt]
```